# How to listen to change in specific field of a nested array in mongodb change streams?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, changestream

This is the structure of BSON document I have in mongodb.

```
{
    "tournament_id": "P1oi12mwj10b1b",
    "matches": [
        {
            "date_order": 1,
            "matches": [
                {
                    "match_id": "1A4i0sp34"
                    "time_order": 1,
                    "win": "team1",
                    "team1": "bar",
                    "team2": "psg"
                },
                {
                    "match_id": "3A4j0sp26"
                    "time_order": 2,
                    "win": "",
                    "team1": "rma",
                    "team2": "sev"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "date_order": 2,
            "matches": [
                {
                    "match_id": "2B4k0sp29"
                    "time_order": 1,
                    "win": "",
                    "team1": "manU",
                    "team2": "manC"
                },
                {
                    "match_id": "4A4i0sp31"
                    "time_order": 2,
                    "win": "",
                    "team1": "chelsea",
                    "team2": "arsenal"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to make a notification system which sends notification whenever a match completes. In other words, whenever the value of `win` field changes, I want to catch which match was updated. I'm using mongodb change streams.

For example, if match with **match_id** *3A4j0sp26* just completed, I want to print that object.

```
{
      "match_id": "3A4j0sp26"
      "time_order": 2,
      "win": "team2",
      "team1": "rma",
      "team2": "sev"
      # If possible I also want to find these fields,
      "tournament_id": "P1oi12mwj10b1b",
      "date_order": 1
}
```

I tried doing this.

```py
import pymongo
from bson.json_util import dumps

MONGO_URI = 'mongodb://localhost/mydb'
client = pymongo.MongoClient(MONGO_URI)

filters = []  # How to correctly set this filter ???
'''
What I already tried but failed
filters = [{
        '$match': {
            '$and': [
                {'updateDescription.updatedFields.matches': {'$exists': 'true'}},  # This line needs fixing.
                {'operationType': {'$in': ['replace', 'update']}}
            ]
        }
    }]
'''


change_stream = client.mydb.match.watch(filters)
for change in change_streams:
    print(dumps(change))
```

I tried to debug without applying filters. I updated `win` field of `match_id` *3A4j0sp26* to **team2**.
I get this as result.

```
{
  "_id": {
    "_data": "8261252C2F000000012B022C0100296E5A1004D4D1F2A9AF33491089DE8C2A51537EBB46645F6964006461228AE88CF6743D054B8CEF0004"
  },
  "operationType": "replace",
  "clusterTime": {
    "$timestamp": {
      "t": 1629826095,
      "i": 1
    }
  },
  "fullDocument": {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "61228ae88cf6743d054b8cef"
    },
    "tournament_id": "P1oi12mwj10b1b",
    "matches": [
        {
            "date_order": 1,
            "matches": [
                {
                    "match_id": "1A4i0sp34"
                    "time_order": 1,
                    "win": "team1",    # This was updated earlier. I don't want this.
                    "team1": "bar",
                    "team2": "psg"
                },
                {
                    "match_id": "3A4j0sp26"
                    "time_order": 2,
                    "win": "team1",     # This is the most recently updated.
                    "team1": "rma",
                    "team2": "sev"
                }
            ]
        }]
   }
}
```

It shows all elements from the array and not the one which was just updated.

**Edited**

Result I got after updating "score" field only.

```
{
  "_id": {
    "_data": "8261254598000000022B022C0100296E5A1004D4D1F2A9AF33491089DE8C2A51537EBB46645F6964006461228AE88CF6743D054B8CEF0004"
  },
  "operationType": "update",
  "clusterTime": {
    "$timestamp": {
      "t": 1629832600,
      "i": 2
    }
  },
  "ns": {
    "db": "mydb",
    "coll": "match"
  },
  "documentKey": {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "61228ae88cf6743d054b8cef"
    }
  },
  "updateDescription": {
    "updatedFields": {
       "matches": [
        {
            "date_order": 1,
            "matches": [
                {
                    "match_id": "1A4i0sp34"
                    "time_order": 1,
                    "win": "team1",
                    "team1": "bar",
                    "team2": "psg"
                },
                {
                    "match_id": "3A4j0sp26"
                    "time_order": 2,
                    "win": "team1",
                    "team1": "rma",
                    "team2": "sev"
                }
            ]
        }]
   },
     "removedFields": []
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Try running an unfiltered change stream, and then modifying that field, to see what the change event looks like.

Comment: @Joe, I have attached the result of unfiltered stream too. Please check. It prints the whole array, so we can't distinguish which was the most recent change.

Comment: That's because you did full document replacement instead of updating the field, so no comparison with the previous document was done.  If you modify just the changed fields when doing the update, the change stream will tell you which fields were modified.

Comment: I tried updating that one field only. `operationType` is shown as `update` now. But, it still showing the whole array in `updatedFields` and not just the one that was updated. Is knowing which element in array was updated an impossible thing to find with mongodb ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you do the update.

A short test to demonstrate:

Insert a document and start a change stream

```
PRIMARY> db.updtest.insert({list:[
                         {item:"1",state:"running"},
                         {item:"2",state:"done"},
                         {item:"3",state:"unknown"}
                  ]});

WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })

PRIMARY> let stream = db.updtest.watch()
```

Updating by setting the list field results in a change event that returns the entire array:

```
PRIMARY> db.updtest.updateOne({},{$set:{list:[
                         {item:"1",state:"running"},
                         {item:"2",state:"done"},
                         {item:"3",state:"running"}
                  ]}});

{ "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : 1, "modifiedCount" : 1 }

PRIMARY> stream.next();

{
    "_id" : {
        "_data" : "82612577BE000000012B022C0100296E5A100436BFE3F91AF84C7CB04826F361BCE50346645F696400646125779D98787C286C5443050004"
    },
    "operationType" : "update",
    "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1629845438, 1),
    "ns" : {
        "db" : "test",
        "coll" : "updtest"
    },
    "documentKey" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("6125779d98787c286c544305")
    },
    "updateDescription" : {
        "updatedFields" : {
            "list" : [
                {
                    "item" : "1",
                    "state" : "running"
                },
                {
                    "item" : "2",
                    "state" : "done"
                },
                {
                    "item" : "3",
                    "state" : "running"
                }
            ]
        },
        "removedFields" : [ ]
    }
}
```

Updating just one field in one subdocument results in a change event that include only the modified field:

```
PRIMARY> db.updtest.update({"list.item":"3"},{$set:{"list.$.state":"done"}});

WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })

PRIMARY> stream.next();

{
    "_id" : {
        "_data" : "8261257879000000012B022C0100296E5A100436BFE3F91AF84C7CB04826F361BCE50346645F696400646125779D98787C286C5443050004"
    },
    "operationType" : "update",
    "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1629845625, 1),
    "ns" : {
        "db" : "test",
        "coll" : "updtest"
    },
    "documentKey" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("6125779d98787c286c544305")
    },
    "updateDescription" : {
        "updatedFields" : {
            "list.2.state" : "done"
        },
        "removedFields" : [ ]
    }
}
```

If you also use the change stream option to return the full documents, you will have the context around the field that was changed.